# Compare 2 rows on different sheets with if condition in vba

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, if-statement, nested

I don't have much coding experinece and I am trying to figure out how I can compare every cell of two different rows on two different sheets. I tried to do it with nested for loops but even thought the code runs through, I am not getting any results.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub masterexpenses()

Dim finalrow2 As Integer
Dim finalrow3 As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Integer

Sheets("PersonnelData").Activate
finalrow2 = Sheets("RawExpenses").Range("U100").End(xlUp).Row
finalrow3 = Sheets("PersonnelData").Range("C100").End(xlUp).Row

For r = 2 To finalrow3
    For i = 2 To finalrow2
        If Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 3) = Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 20) Then
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 20).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 7)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 21).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 10)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 22).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 13)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 23).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 16)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 24).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 19)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 25).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 22)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 26).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 25)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 27).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 28)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 28).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 31)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 29).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 34)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 30).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 37)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 31).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 40)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 32).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 43)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 33).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 46)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 34).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 49)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 35).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 52)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 36).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 55)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 37).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 58)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 38).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 61)
        Sheets("RawExpenses").Cells(i, 39).copy Destination:=Sheets("PersonnelData").Cells(r, 64)
        End If
    Next i
Next r

End Sub
```

Your would be much appreciated. I am trying to figure out this thing for quite a while now...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What text do you have in RawExpenses.Cells(2, 20) and PersonnelData.Cells(2, 3)? Can you provide some more values to be compared?

Comment: There are personnel numbers in those cells. That means, I want to add the expenses of one employee from the RawExpenses sheet to the PersonnelData Sheet if the personnel numbers on both sheets are the same.

Comment: I've solved my issue with a VLOOKUP function. Still curious though why my code didn't work